# How could I disable Jhipster local repository auto commit feature after generation?

Tags: jhipster

Is there any way that I can block Jhipster from committing in my local repository after generation?

If I import new . jdl or force to regenerate, Jhipster automatically committing new changes in my local repository without my permission. Please advice on this.

Comment: Have you tried the `--skip-git`option? https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#3

Comment: --skip-git works for me

Answer (score -1):

try removing husky from the `packages.json`

```
yarn remove husky
```

or

```
npm uninstall husky
```

husky is provided by jhipster to manage your jhipster project's git